# Functional interface to IO::Compress::Gzip is not handling arguments correctly

Tags: perl, gzip

Here is a simple example to illustrate the issue I am seeing when trying to use IO::Compress::Gzip:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

eval {
    require IO::Compress::Gzip;
    IO::Compress::Gzip->import();
    1;
} or do {
    my $error = $@;
        die "\nERROR: Couldn't load IO::Compress::Gzip" if $error;
};

my $input = shift;
my $out = $input.".gz";
print "Defined!\n" if defined $out;

IO::Compress::Gzip::gzip $input => $out 
    or die "gzip failed: $!\n";
```

This generates the following error:

```
Defined!
Use of uninitialized value $_[1] in string eq at /home/statonse/perl/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.22.0/lib/5.22.0/IO/Compress/Base/Common.pm line 280.
IO::Compress::Gzip::gzip: output filename is undef or null string at test.pl line 17.
```

However, if I use the object interface:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

eval {
    require IO::Compress::Gzip;
    IO::Compress::Gzip->import();
    1;
} or do {
    my $error = $@;
    die "\nERROR: Couldn't load IO::Compress::Gzip" if $error;
};

my $input = shift;
my $out = $input.".gz";
print "Defined!\n" if defined $out;

my $z = new IO::Compress::Gzip $out
    or die "IO::Compress::Gzip failed: $!\n";

$z->print($input);
```

It works just fine. For some context, it would work as normal if I imported the module with use:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Compress::Gzip;

my $input = shift;
my $out = $input.".gz";

IO::Compress::Gzip::gzip $input => $out
    or die "gzip failed: $!\n";
```

but I am trying to avoid that since this library is rarely used in the application. Is there something obvious I am doing wrong or is this a behavior specific to this module?

Comment: Side note: You should avoid [indirect object notation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Indirect-Object-Syntax). Change `my $z = new IO::Compress::Gzip $out` to `my $z = IO::Compress::Gzip->new($out)`. See [The Problems with Indirect Object Notation](http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2009/08/the-problems-with-indirect-object-notation.html).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I agree, that was copied from the module docs for a test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
IO::Compress::Gzip::gzip $input => $out
```

is parsed differently depending on whether the parser knows that there is a function called `IO::Compress::Gzip::gzip` or not.

When you load the library with `use`, its functions are known to the parser before the rest of your program is parsed (because `use` is a type of `BEGIN`). In this case the parser chooses the interpretation you want.

In the other case, it chooses the alternate interpretation: indirect object syntax, equivalent to `$input->IO::Compress::Gzip::gzip, $out`

You can see this for yourself by running `perl -MO=Deparse` on the different versions of your program.

The fix is to make the function call explicit with parentheses:

```
IO::Compress::Gzip::gzip($input, $out)
```

The parser can't misinterpret that.

Comment: And in case it's not clear, you should *always* use parentheses when the sub is not predeclared/imported (unless it takes no arguments). This means all method calls, since method invocants are not resolved until run-time. See tobyink's response to ["to paren or not to paren"](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1083904) on PerlMonks.

Comment: Great explanation as to why it doesn't work the other way. Thanks!